# react-native-webp loads some wep images but not all

Tags: amazon-s3, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using this module `react-native-webp` to load webp images on ios. However, I am not seeing the images from s3 load. Using an image found from google search, works fine. There are absolutely no logs whatsoever to help debug the issue!

This is an example url that doesn't load: http://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/rupyacard/offers/pictures/000/000/007/1280/dinner.webp

And this here is one that's loading just fine! https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp

Can't find a reason for either to not work. I thought it might have to do with the image size but a smaller version doesn't help either. Here's a smaller variant: http://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/rupyacard/offers/pictures/000/000/007/320/dinner.webp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give path images to HTTPS or just do following settings in xcode and clean  rebuild app

The main problem is Apple can't load HTTP images without settings.

[image]